# @font-face rendering in existing PDF

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I have below HTML:

```
String css = "@font-face {" 
        + "font-family: myFont;" 
        + "src: url(fonts/COMICATE.TTF);" 
        + "-fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;" 
        + "-fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;" 
        + "}"
        + "font-family: myFont;}";
String html = "<html><head>"+css+"</head><body><p>Hello My Font</p></body></html>";
```

I have below `flyingsaucer` code to convert the above `HTML` to `PDF`, and it worked perfect. It does render the **Hello My Font** with my custom font-family `COMICATE.TTF`

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
String outputFile = "result.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.close();
```

I have below `iText` code to place the above `HTML` at absolute position, and it works perfect except `@font-face` in `css`.

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(cb);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(800, 800, 100, 100);
ElementList elements = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, "");  // I want to embed flyingsaucer generated html with custom font here
for (Element element : elements) {
    columnText.addElement(element);
}
columnText.go();
```

Is there any way that I can take help of `flyingsaucer` for the html conversion and then place it in my existing PDF using `iText`? Or any other alternatives to achieve above using `iText`?

**UPDATE**

I can use custom font with below code using iText and it works perfectly but I need to use HTML+CSS.

```
Font font = FontFactory.getFont("fonts/COMICATE.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 0.8f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
BaseFont baseFont = font.getBaseFont();
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(1);
cb.setFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);
cb.beginText();
cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Hello My Font", 150, 760, 0);
cb.endText();
```

Comment: FYI: Flying Saucer is a third party project that is not supported by iText Group. Converting HTML+CSS is usually done using iText's [XML Worker](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker).

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I have figured it out by implementing custom `FontFactoryImp` it worked without Flying Saucer.